# Does $\sup_{t \leq T} |M_{n_k}(t)-M_{m_k}(t)|\to 0$ imply $\lim_k M_{n_k}(t)$ exists and is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, convergence-divergence

This came up in proving that $\mathcal{M}^2_c$ is a complete metric space using the invariant metric induced by
$$
||M|| = \sum_k \frac{||M(k)||_2\wedge 1}{2^n}.
$$

Suppose $M_n(t)$ is a sequence of continuous martingales such that
$$
E \sup_{t \leq T} |M_n(t)-M_m(t)|^2 \to 0
$$
as $m,n \to \infty$.
I would like to say "then $M_n$ is uniformly Cauchy along a subsequence" and hence converges to a continuous limit, but I stumble when I actually try to put to words why.

Certainly, for any $n_k,m_k \to \infty$ I may choose a subsequence of indices (WLOG the whole sequence) such that $\sup_{t \leq T} |M_{n_k}(t)-M_{m_k}(t)|\to 0$ a.s. Is this enough to conclude that the a.s. limit $\lim_k M_{n_k}(t)$ is continuous? I feel like there should be some simple way to show that $N_k := M_{n_k}$ is actually uniformly Cauchy which would finish the proof.

Edit: Obviously if $m_k=n_k$ then we can't conclude anything. Assume $m_k=n_k+1$ for all $k$.

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about Martingales, but it seems to me you're kind of asking about when a sequence of continuous functions converges to a continuous function, and the answer is you need uniform convergence (which you have). Let $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N$ such that $\sup_x |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \leq \epsilon/3$ for all $n,m \geq N$. For this $N$, $f_N$ is continuous, so choose $\delta > 0$ such that $|f_N(x)-f_N(y)|<\epsilon/3$ for $|x-y| < \delta$. Then
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |f(x) - f_N(x)|+|f_N(x)-f_N(y)|+|f_N(y)-f(y)| < \epsilon.$$ With $f_n = M_n$, looks about right.

Comment: What if you consider each $M_n$ as an element of the space of vector-valued "functions" $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal C([0,T]))$, where $\Omega$ is your underlying probability space. Then your assumption looks like "$(M_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal C([0,T]))$", i.e. $(M_n)$ is convergent in this space. So there should be an almost surely convergent subsequence, which is what you want. Does it look correct?

Comment: @Etienne I am not familiar with the notation $L^2(\Omega,C[0,T])$ since $C[0,T]$ is neither a $\sigma$-algebra nor a measure... Can you reference somewhere that defines this notation?

Comment: This is the space of $L^2$ "functions" with values in the Banach space $\mathcal C([0,T])$, the space of continuous functions on $[0,T]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption,

$$\mathbb{E}\left( \sup_{t \leq T} |M_n(t)-M_m(t)|^2 \right) \to 0$$

as $m,n \to \infty$ which means that $(M_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2(\Omega,\mathbb{P};C[0,T])$, i.e. the space of functions

$$\Omega \ni \omega \mapsto f(\omega) \in C[0,T]$$

endowed with the norm

$$\|f\|_{L^2}^2 = \int \|f(\omega)\|_{\infty}^2 \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int \sup_{t \leq T} |f(\omega,t)|^2 \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \tag{1}$$

where $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ denotes the supremum norm. Since this space is complete (see Lemma below), we conclude that there exists $M \in L^2(\Omega,\mathbb{P};C[0,T])$ such that $M_n \to M$ in $L^2(\Omega,\mathbb{P};C[0,T])$, i.e.

$$\mathbb{E}\left( \sup_{t \leq T} |M_n(t)-M(t)|^2 \right) \to 0$$

as $n \to \infty$. Consequently, there exists a subsequence such that

$$\sup_{t \leq T} |M_{n(k)}(t)-M(t)| \to 0 \quad (k \to \infty)$$

This means that $M$ is a uniform limit of continuous functions, thus continuous.

---

**Lemma** $L^2(\Omega,\mathbb{P};C[0,T])$ endowed with the norm defined in $(1)$ is complete.

Proof: Note that the mapping defined in $(1)$ is indeed a norm. It suffices to show that for any sequence $(f_n)_n \subseteq L^2(\Omega,\mathbb{P};C[0,T])$ such that $$\sum_{k \geq 1} \|f_k\|_{L^2} < \infty$$ the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f_k$ exists.  By triangle inequality, we have

$$\left( \int \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \|f_j\|_{\infty} \right)^2 \, d\mathbb{P} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \left\| \sum_{j=1}^n \|f_j\|_{\infty} \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{P})} \leq \sum_{j=1}^n \bigg\| \|f_j\|_{\infty} \bigg\|_{L^2(\mathbb{P})} \leq \sum_{j \geq 1} \|f_j\|_{L^2}$$

By the monotone convergence theorem, we conclude that

$$\int \bigg(\underbrace{\sum_{j \geq 1} \|f_j\|_{\infty}}_{=:g}\bigg)^2 \, d\mathbb{P}< \infty$$

in particular $g<\infty$ a.s.. Therefore,

$$f(\omega,t) := \sum_{j \geq 1} f_j(\omega,t) \qquad (\omega \in \Omega, t \leq T)$$

exists a.s. and the series converges a.s. uniformly in $t$. Since

$$\left\| f(\omega)- \sum_{j=1}^n f_j(\omega) \right\|_{\infty} \leq \sum_{j \geq n+1} \|f_j(\omega)\|_{\infty} \leq g(\omega) \in L^2(\mathbb{P})$$

the claim follows by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: I don't think the top condition implies the limit exists. E.g. if $M_0=0$ and $M_{n+1}=M_{n}+1/n$ then $|M_{n+1}-M_{n}| = 1/n \to 0$ but $M_n \to \infty$.

Comment: @nullUser ... but in this example there does **not** exist a subsequence such that $$\sup_{t \leq T} |M_{n(k)}(t)-M_{m(k)}(t)| \to 0 \quad (k \to \infty)$$ That uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence is a basic fact from the calculus lecture: Obviously, $$|M_{n(k)}(t)-M_{m(k)}(t)| \leq \sup_{t \leq T} |M_{n(k)}(t)-M_{m(k)}(t)| \to 0 \quad (k \to \infty)$$ which means that $(M_{n(k)}(t))_{k \geq 0}$ is for fixed $t$ a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore convergent.

Comment: $\sup_t 1/k$ certainly does tend to zero as $k \to \infty$...

Comment: @nullUser That's obviously true. But: If $(M_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{M}_2^T$ (with the given norm), this means that for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can choose $n_0$ such that for $m,n \geq n_0$, we have $$\mathbb{E}\sup_t |M_n(t)-M_m(t)|^2 \leq \varepsilon$$ And that's **not** satisfied for your given example.

Comment: But I'm going to edit my answer, so that it becomes (hopefully) clearer.

Comment: Much clearer, thank you for this!